# Python - pypsexec command with arguments

Tags: python-3.x, parameter-passing

I am trying to run the below script that triggers a job on a remote windows server. It sends only the first part "Daily" and doesnt not include complete string(with space) "Daily File load". Tried with "Daily/ File/ Load" and it throws error "Daily/ " is invalid job name.

```
from pypsexec.client import Client
client.run_executable(
executable=’C:\programs\Scheduler.exe’
, arguments="Daily File Load")
```

Comment: Please provide full traceback

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
arguments="/c Daily File Load"
```

It should work